# How to use Beanshell Server in Jmeter to serve http requests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

In my current project, I have  a situation where my Web application calls a third party URL with some event Data. Then the third party URL is supposed to call back to my application to gather further details.

I want to create a stub or substitute for the third party URL in Jmeter, which keep listening for a call from my application and then initiate an API test thread group from within the JMETER.

Is this possible? Can any one guide if Beanshell server can help here? if yes how?

Comment: just curious - For functional testing, stub is ok. what is the use of doing the performance testing with stub?

Comment: why do you want you use a stub, when it is possible to do the above scenario with the actual application?